# Offset code not working to replace data in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have replaced cells in a column that previously had #N/A to reflect "A" however when i run the below code the value "A" doesn't get changed to the offset i have chosen below. Can you please advise? Thanks in advance!

```
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("O2:O" & ActiveSheet.Range("O65536").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each c In SrchRng
    If c.Value = "A" Then
        c.Offset(0, -2).Value = c.Offset(0, -2).Value
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("O2:O" & ActiveSheet.Range("O65536").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each c In SrchRng
    If c.Value = "A" Then
        c.Offset(0, -2).Value = c.Offset(0, -2).Value
    End If
Next c
```

So... we are getting a range which is comprised of `O2:O<last populated row>`. Then we loop through that range. If a cell is found with the value "A" then we set the value of the cell two columns to the left of that cell with it's own value. `c.Offset(0, -2).Value = c.Offset(0, -2).Value` Why set the value of this cell to itself. It's already it's own value.

Perhaps you meant `c.Value = c.Offset(0, -2).Value`

Comment: Thanks! That worked, not sure why the original code works in other macros on the same workbook.